# Logistic regression for medical statistics -- Conflict between results by Mathematica and other statistical softwares

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

Actually, I am trying to recover an example in a textbook via *Mathematica*. The situation is to study the relationship between 
esophagus cancer and smoking as well as excessive drinking. And the original data is quite simple:

```
data = {{0, 0, 199, 63, 136},
        {0, 1, 170, 63, 107},
        {1, 0, 101, 44, 57},
        {1, 1, 416, 265, 151}};
```

where in each row (sub-list), the entries are for x1 (smoking: no-0, yes-1), x2 (excessive drinking: no-0, yes-1), total number, number of positive and number of negative (total number = number of positive + number of negative).

The textbook gives, e.g., the estimate and standard error of the linear coefficients b0 (Intercept), b1 and b2 as (picture coming from http://statpages.info/logistic.html)

[image]

---

However, when I use `LogitModelFit` (which accepts data with structure `{{x1, x2, y},...}`, and `y` is the ratio of positive samples: number of positive / total number) with the below new data

```
dataNew = {{0., 0., 0.316583},
           {0., 1., 0.370588},
           {1., 0., 0.435644},
           {1., 1., 0.637019}};
logitM = LogitModelFit[dataNew, {x1, x2}, {x1, x2}];
```

Then `logitM["ParameterTable"]` gives

[image]

The problem is that the results obtained by *Mathematica* do not accord with those by the textbook.

---

So my first questions are:

1. Have I used `LogitModelFit` correctly?
2. How could one get the consistent results as shown in the first picture?

---

P.S. I am using Windows 10 and Mathematica 11.2.

### ------------------------------

Conclusion to Question 1: I indeed did not use `LogitModelFit` correctly.

Conclusion to Question 2: See the selected answer.

And thanks a lot to @JimB and @J. M..

Comment: "an example in a textbook" - can you mention which textbook, please?

Comment: @J.M. The textbook is in Chinese. If necessary, I could translate it.

Comment: Hmm... did the textbook at least mention what software they were using that generated those results?

Comment: @J.M. The software used in the textbook is SPSS.

Comment: I don't have access to SPSS at the moment, but indeed I am getting conflicting results from *Mathematica* and the webpage you linked to. Let me check further...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably should use `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` given the structure of your data.  One needs to turn the data into an array of the following form:  {smoking, drinking,status}:

```
newdata = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1},
           {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}};
```

Then construct the `Weights` from the associated frequency counts:

```
weights = Flatten[{data[[All, 4]], data[[All, 5]]}];
```

The analysis is performed by

```
glm = GeneralizedLinearModelFit[
   newdata, {smoking, drinking}, {smoking, drinking}, 
   ExponentialFamily -> "Binomial", Weights -> weights];
glm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Table of estimated coefficients]

***Update***

You actually can fit the model with the same structure using `LogitModelFit`:

```
lmf = LogitModelFit[newdata, {smoking, drinking}, {smoking, drinking}, Weights -> weights];
lmf["ParameterTable"]
```

Comment: Ah, that's more like it! So, `LogitModelFit[]` is broken here?

Comment: Sorry @J.M.  I was too slow.  It's not broken.  I just have a tendency/bias to use `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` rather than the more specialized functions (`LogitModelFit`, `ProbitModelFit`, etc.).  But I added the use of `LogitModelFit` in the answer.

Comment: @JimB Thank you very much!

Comment: @J.M. Also thank you for your timely response!